# Prevent ASP.NET MVC from validating id mismatch between URL and JSON property

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

It seems that ASP.NET MVC throws an argument exception if the URL parameter value doesn't match the JSON property value of the same name. For example, using the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Let's say I create an endpoint that looks like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Webhooks(string id)
        {
          // do something
        }
}
```

If the following request is sent:

```
POST http://something.com/test/webhooks/foo HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"id": "bar"}
```

...then MVC will throw an ArgumentException because the id value `bar` doesn't match the id in the URL `foo`.

If I change the Content-Type to something other than application/json, this problem doesn't occur (presumably b/c MVC won't try to read the payload). This seems to only happen in production as well.

How can we prevent MVC from doing this validation?

Comment: Would you need the value to be taken from the body if its not present in the URL?

Comment: My initial though would be to use a custom value provider by implementing `IValueProvider`. Sorry I am not familiar with the details.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this.  You are asking it to accept conflicting values for the `id` parameter by making some decision about which value takes precedence.  While you might be able to get it to do this, wouldn't it be better not to create the conflict in the first place?  Either the `id` is `foo` or it is `bar`.

Comment: Cannot duplicate this at all. The value of `id` is "bar" in the POST method (which is what it should be - the JsonValueProvider wins over the RouteValueProvider). What are the exact details of the error message? (the only error I could generate from this is if I did not stringify the data but that was a different error)

Comment: And removing the `contentType` option just means that it will use the default (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`) - its still sent in the request, but will use the FormValueProvider (which also wins) so the value of the parameter will still be "bar"